# Ubuntu Apache2 permissions And settings

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, apache2

good day, I'm writing because I installed Linux Ubuntu server 16.04 and installed Apache2, the classic welcoming Apache page works, but when I create index.html so it throws up the bug and does not want to do anything, I create files, etc using FTP. I'm a newcomer and I do not understand permissions at all, I'd like to set it up so I can write and read files, but other people just read and do not write a bug forbidden 403 and you have no rights. thanks. (I do not speak English, I'm from the Czech Republic and translate using google translator)

Comment: Your question and details will be easier to read if you would use punctuation between thoughts and put the error messages on a separate line.  The Google translator is mixing the error message into your words, whereas it's adding some confusion to your description.  Please type the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Your question doesn't have enough information. Find a guide to setup Apache2 in google and follow it step by step. If something goes wrong, ask a question with all the commands, logs and errors that you get. Without that is very difficult to help you. You will have to learn about permissions to work in linux. This will probably not work but try it: `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/yourfolder -R;sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Hi Mr. Dan. Please add the specific error message(s) to your question.